# Difference between .resumeWith(Result.failure(...)) and .resumeWithException

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I might be missing some fundamental understanding of coroutines and continuations in Kotlin, but I couldn't find any information on the difference between

```kotlin
Continuation<T>.resumeWith(Result.failure(/* some exception */))
// and
Continuation<T>.resumeWithException(/* some exception */)
```

and the same for

```kotlin
Continuation<T>.resumeWith(Result.success(/* some value */))
// and
Continuation<T>.resume(/* some value */)
```

When should which one be used and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It requires just a quick look at the source:
[image]

And yeah you are right it's exactly the same. The only difference is the amount of code you have to write

Comment: Ah I completely forgot that was a thing you could do haha

Comment: hahah yes. It's very handy just press `Ctrl` + `B`

Answer (score 3):

It all comes down to usage of [`Result`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-result/) - its main purpose is to encapsulate success/failure as handling exception results from (bulk of) asynchronous calls using try/catch gets really messy.

You can read through original [Result API Proposal on Github](https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/stdlib/result.md) to see more samples and motivation of why this api was created.

Answer (score 0):

> When should which one be used?

`resumeWith(Result<T>)` should be used when you already have a value of type `Result<T>` encapsulating either a successful outcome, or a failure.

Otherwise, when you have either a value of type `T` indicating a successful continuation or an exception indicating a failure, it's more convenient to use `resume` and `resumeWithException` shortcuts respectively.